# Using Guzzle with SELinux setenforce 1

Tags: 8

is there anyway to run drupal 8 with guzzle to access remote server rest server without turning off selinux.

for example in httpd, i can do:

> setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail on

to be able to make apache send email without turning off selinux.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a Linux command line tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is:

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

Comment: By the way, you can see all selinux booleans like this:

     `semanage boolean -l`